# Non Hex Based hash Code

Tags: hash, md5, sha1

to make long story short. I was given a Hash code generated from a file, but was not told what kind of function it was generated with. The Hash code was: "IRV4RRFX3Q62YIXLBJMEXANLDE3JPVFT"

If i was right in could not be MD5 or sha1 because these are Hex based driven, so it must be something like base64.

Do someone know what kind of Hash gerenerator this was generated with? 
Or if it is not even a legal Hash?

thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Re: "could not be MD5 or sha1 because these are Hex based driven": This is not correct. MD5 and SHA-1 simply output sequences of bytes. The most common way to stringify those byte-sequences is as hex, but it is not at all the only way. Many libraries have functions like `md5_base64` to produce MD5 hashes stringified using Base-64 instead. (That said, your code is too long to be a Base-64 representation of either of those hashes. And it's wildly improbable to end up with a 32-character Base-64 string consisting solely of uppercase letters and digits.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to know for sure from the information provided, but it may be base32 of a SHA1 hash.

Using [this base32 converter](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base32.php?lang=en) gives me a hex string of 446BC8C4B7DC3DAC22EB0A584B81AB193697D4B3, which is the right length for a SHA1 hash.

Comment: +1. I hadn't heard of Base32 before, but it makes sense: SHA-1 outputs a 160-bit string, and Base32 implies log₂(32) = 5 bits per character, so it gives 160/5 = 32 characters. And [the Wikipedia article on Base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) says its character set is 2-7 plus A-Z, which matches the OP's string.

Comment: Is base32 used for identifiy a File? never heard of it.

Comment: base32 is just an encoding like hex or base64 are, so it could be used in the same kinds of scenarios. I haven't knowingly seen it in use in practice before though.

Comment: Ah ok like, the same information but in a diffrent language or fromat!

Comment: Thank you, to all the fine replys :-D